# cross-compiling application to work on older linux operating system

Tags: cmake, centos7, cross-compiling, toolchain, trilinos

I need to cross-compile my application to run on a target machine using centos7. I am basing myself in the following cross-compilation repository https://github.com/tttapa/cross-python. This repository has a makefile to set up a toolchain with several libraries. However, my application has other depencies which are not in this toolcain libraries. The libraries I need to add to this toolchain are Sacado and Kokkos (both from Trilinos).

Based on the Makefile of this repository, which can install the toolchain and all the libraries, I tried to add a part to install kokkos as well but I did not managed to make it work. Anyone who has experience cross-copiling trilinos packages?

Comment: Why do you need to cross-compile? Can you spin up the target system in a VM?

Comment: I don't know, is just a way I found to do it. As you noticed, I am a rookie in this subject, and it seemed like a doable way of compiling the application to a target machine. I was advised by the owner of the repository to do it like this

Comment: I would try running target system in Docker and compiling in there. Usually this is easier.

Comment: but the repository already has a dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

FYI: pypa provide manylinux container to build "manylinux" native python package.
This should be ok to build wheel package working on centos-7

see: https://github.com/pypa/manylinux